# Record not always found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Consider the following

```
# setup an array of the question ids so far
questions_array = []
questions_array.push(session[:questions_array])

# take a random question whom id is not included in the session[:questions_array]
@question = Question.offset(rand(Question.count)).where('id NOT IN (?)',questions_array).take

# push id to array and later on assign the new array to the session
questions_array.push(@question.id)
session[:questions_array] = questions_array
```

I have two questions database. One of the two gets returned the other one gives me the error

`NoMethodError (undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass):`

this line gives the error `questions_array.push(@question.id)`

this does not happen everytime! and that is what's strange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how, you can solve it though:

```
Question
  .where.not(id: questions_array)
  .order('random()')
  .first
```

But if the questions table get say more than 10,000 records for example, it will be slow. Then you could write recursive procedure, which will pick a random record and check some condition. if condition matches, returns the record, or recursion will go on with some base condition to break in worst case.

Comment: hmm tried this just now, it gives me same error "NoMethodError (undefined method `id'

Comment: EDIT: if i change your `.limit(1)` to `.first` it works!

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou fixed, and please accept it, if you think it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My bad seems that the problem lies in the fact that i first get a random id and then check if that id is not in the array which is not what i wanted. So if the random id was included in the array it would give an error as there is none to take.

this is the new line of code.

`@question = Question.where('id NOT IN (?)',questions_array).first`

Comment: ..or, your `offset` can also be the reason. suppose, you got 3 records from `where` filter, and then offset is set as 4 or anything more then 3, and in this cases you will get `nil`. :)

Comment: how would you write it differently so that i would not give me a record i got once before?

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you are trying to achieve. ?

Comment: Its a test. A series of random questions one after the other. What i want is not to repeat questions that were shown before to the user.